# Is this balcony Endermen-proof?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have this pseudo-functional (but mostly for aesthetics) balcony just outside my mountain-side shelter:

[image]

It gives me a nice view outside, and I can peer over the edge to the ground far below (30+ blocks) to see what baddies are down there before I venture out.

There is an above overhang that extends a couple of blocks past the balcony edge (not shown), so no monsters can fall down onto it from above. What I'm not sure about is whether it's Endermen-proof. I've noticed them appearing on occassion on the mountain to the right. I've also tussled with a few of them underground and know they have a penchant for teleporting behind you when they get cross. However, in my experience they seem to have trouble moving/teleporting through passages that narrow in height to less than 3 blocks. The narrowest height of my balcony opening is 2 1/2 blocks, where the slabs are in the picture.

If I were on my balcony, and an Enderman caught sight of me, would he be able to pop on over to my balcony uninvited? Or would he not be able to fit through? Since I don't really *need* the balcony, I could probably glass-block it in. But I kind of like it as-is. It amuses me.

Comment: I'm not certain of this, but couldn't the Endermen teleport into the part of the building you're standing on in this screenshot since it is 3 blocks high?

Comment: Are you asking if they will wander in on their own or if you anger them? Anger, if the can stand where you are they will just appear there.. as for wandering in I think you are ok.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Endermen **teleport** close to you when you look away. In other words, if the room you are standing in is tall enough, a narrow balcony won't stop them.

Comment: So, the size of openings between you and them don't matter? I mistakenly thought this because they didn't teleport when I managed to get on the opposite side of a two-block high opening while fighting them. I guess the real reason they didn't teleport was because I backed through the opening and was looking right at them the whole time. Is there a limit to how far they can move in one teleport?

Comment: @gnovice I think you should ask this follow-up question separately.

Comment: @k0pernikus: Good idea. I'll ask it shortly.

Comment: Well, to be on the safe side I glass-blocked up my balcony. Oh well, no more high diving for me. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Based on the Minecraft wiki, the vertical teleport limit of the Endermen is 3 blocks.  So a balcony that is 3 blocks up is Enderman safe.

Remember that spiders can climb, and skeletons have a long ranged line of sight. In my city's walls, they can shoot me.

Comment: This fits with my experience trying to build an Endermen-hunting lodge. Once I aggroed them, they simply refused to teleport up to my awesome rooftop battle arena.